# How to perform an exponential fit on date data?

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I have some data in this format:

```
0,1/19/20
0,1/20/20
0,1/21/20
1,1/22/20
6,1/23/20
7,1/24/20
11,1/25/20
15,1/26/20
28,1/27/20
38,1/28/20
```

and I want to plot it along with an exponential curve that fits.
This is what I'm trying:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal svg enhance background rgb "white"
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y"
set xdata time
set format x "%m/%d/%y"
f(x)=a*exp(x*b)
a=1
b=0.00000000001
fit f(x) "test.dat" using 2:1 via a,b
plot "test.dat" using 2:1, f(x)
```

but this is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrdYq.jpg

output:

```
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a             b            
   0 2.4518484242e+03   0.00e+00  7.18e-01    1.000000e+00   1.000000e-11
   1 1.0605090928e+03  -1.31e+05  7.18e-02    1.397524e+01   1.205276e-11
   2 1.0548499551e+03  -5.36e+02  7.18e-03    1.473392e+01   1.761422e-11
   * 1.1929533566e+03   1.16e+04  7.18e-02    5.600970e+00   4.096647e-10
   3 1.0548479644e+03  -1.89e-01  7.18e-03    1.463642e+01   2.152072e-11
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a             b            

After 3 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 1054.85
rel. change during last iteration : -1.88724e-06

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 5
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 14.5248
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 210.97

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 14.6364          +/- 4.851e+04    (3.315e+05%)
b               = 2.15207e-11      +/- 2.098e-06    (9.749e+06%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      
a               1.000 
b              -1.000  1.000
```

---

Another case (same format for data, same command):

Plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUrOb.jpg

Output:

```
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a             b            
   0 3.1449068545e+15   0.00e+00  8.39e+07    1.000000e+00   1.000000e-08
   1 4.3978813150e+14  -6.15e+05  8.39e+06    9.961173e-01   9.380902e-09
   2 6.0443707833e+13  -6.28e+05  8.39e+05    9.921770e-01   8.756643e-09
   3 8.2818940310e+12  -6.30e+05  8.39e+04    9.880292e-01   8.132279e-09
   4 1.1307879559e+12  -6.32e+05  8.39e+03    9.783880e-01   7.512240e-09
   5 1.4643178088e+11  -6.72e+05  8.39e+02    7.869411e-01   7.011825e-09
   ...
 223 4.3503512818e+08  -6.75e-01  8.39e+03    7.898096e-31   4.829813e-08
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a             b            

After 223 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 4.35035e+08
rel. change during last iteration : -6.75096e-06

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 55
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 2812.42
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 7.90973e+06

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 7.8981e-31       +/- 1.236e-30    (0%)
b               = 4.82981e-08      +/- 2.01e-07     (416.2%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      
a               1.000 
b              -1.000  1.000 
line 0: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>6e+04)
line 0: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>6e+04)
```

I suspected I was not choosing the right initial parameters for the fitting curve but I've played with many values (especially for b) and sometimes I get **unknown type in real()**.

I've read that when dealing with dates, `x` takes the value of seconds from the beginning of the century. If that's the case then I'm not sure how to make the right operations with that number. I'd also like to get rid of all the xtics and points where y is 0, if that's possible.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm not using the correct fitting function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time data is handled internally as seconds from January, 1st 1970 00:00:00. Check `help time/date`. So, you need to shift your function `f(x)` by your start date and give a reasonable start value especially for `b`.

**Code:**

```
### exponential fit of time data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0,1/19/20
0,1/20/20
0,1/21/20
1,1/22/20
6,1/23/20
7,1/24/20
11,1/25/20
15,1/26/20
28,1/27/20
38,1/28/20
EOD

set datafile separator comma

myTimeFmt = "%m/%d/%y"
set format x "%m/%d" time

# get the start date
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (Start=timecolumn(2,myTimeFmt)) index 0 every ::0:0:0:0 w table
unset table

b=1e8    # reasonable startvalue for fitting
f(x) = a*exp((x-Start)/b*log(2))+c
set fit nolog
fit f(x) $Data u (timecolumn(2,myTimeFmt)):1 via a,b,c

End = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2/11/20")
set xrange[Start:End]
set yrange[0.5:]
set logscale y
set grid xtics, ytics
set key top left

set label 1 at graph 0.01, graph 0.85 sprintf("Doubling every: %.2f days",b/84600.)

plot $Data u (timecolumn(2,myTimeFmt)):1 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue" ti "Data", \
     f(x) w l lc rgb "red" ti "Fit"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Aaah, I see, I was screwing it up with the time. Thanks a lot, this worked!